# Combining two different observables

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Have the following snippet:

```
 Log.d("#######", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView)
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,Schedulers.newThread())
            .flatMap(new Func1<SearchViewQueryTextEvent, Observable<GifsData>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<GifsData> call(SearchViewQueryTextEvent txtChangeEvt) {
                    return RestWebClient.get().getSearchedGifs(txtChangeEvt.queryText().toString(),"dcJmzC");
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<GifsData>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("#######","onCompleted searchGifs");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("#######",e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(GifsData gifsData) {
                   mainFragmentPresenterInterface.displaySearchedGifsList(gifsData);
                }
            });
}
```

No matter what i try i keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from the main thread. Was: Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-2,5,main]
```

Probably have spend close to an hour on this..Haven't been able to figure out what is the issue. Even tried matching my snippet to the following link:

[Combine RxTextView Observable and Retrofit Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391001/combine-rxtextview-observable-and-retrofit-observable)

No luck. Can someone point out what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove this line " .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())" it work properly. Reason is you are accessing views on background thread. Or you can fetch the search text outside of Observable so that view does not get accessed in background thread.

Comment: but i am observing it on the main thread, which is where the views are being manipulated, isnt it?

Comment: I dont see the exception..but the onNext is not getting triggered either

Comment: You are observing result on main thread but subscribing on background thread, hence you are getting this exception.

Comment: Does that mean that all the network calls in the above snippet are NOT being executed in background thread, if i get rid of the subscribeOn

Comment: Please checkout this exampl https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/fragments/DebounceSearchEmitterFragment.java it will help you to fix it

Comment: I did try that example already. That only work if i log or show a toast. But not   if trying to update a list.

Comment: If you not specify .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) then your observable will get executed on default thread, which in your case I think is Main Thread

Comment: Which is not recommended. Hence i had the subscribeOn in place there

Answer (score 2):

Reason of error: You are subscribing result on background thread and you are accessing View in stream on background thread. Here I have invoked `RestWebClient.get().getSearchedGifs(txtChangeEvt.queryText().toString(),"dcJmzC").subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());`on background scheduler .Please try this it will work for you:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(mSearchView)
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Func1<SearchViewQueryTextEvent, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(SearchViewQueryTextEvent txtChangeEvt) {
                    return Observable.just(txtChangeEvt.queryText().toString()).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<GifsData, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<GifsData> call(String txtChangeEvt) {
                    return RestWebClient.get().getSearchedGifs(txtChangeEvt,"dcJmzC").subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<GifsData>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("#######","onCompleted searchGifs");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("#######",e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(GifsData gifsData) {
                    Log.d("#######", gifsData);
                }
            });
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: You have two subscribeOn here. Won't that cause issue. As per my understanding only the first subscribeOn is ever applied on the stream of data. In that case, the getSearchedGifs call will be executed on mainThread. Isn't that right?

Comment: You can subscribe streams on different subscribers. It's perfectly right to have different streams subscriber on different subscribers. Hope someone else jump into this to reply on your comment

Comment: I found the following link as to why multiple subscribeOn works on a flatmapped observables. However the explanation is still convoluted for me. I will upvote the answer as it seems it is in the right direction, but will keep it open until someone can dumb it down as to why subscribeOn works on flatmapping. The link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/XXJJPhn8PHQ

Answer (score 0):

Operator `debounce` by default uses `computation` scheduler, you need to change it to main thread (because you work with UI only on main).

Next thing is to schedule network request to be executed on `io` scheduler.
(we are using only one `subscribeOn` now).

And again observing results on main thread to inreact with UI.

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView)
  .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .flatMap(new Func1<SearchViewQueryTextEvent, Observable<GifsData>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<GifsData> call(SearchViewQueryTextEvent txtChangeEvt) {
      return RestWebClient.get()
        .getSearchedGifs(txtChangeEvt.queryText().toString(),"dcJmzC")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
  })
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Observer<GifsData>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
      Log.d("#######","onCompleted searchGifs");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
      Log.d("#######",e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(GifsData gifsData) {
      mainFragmentPresenterInterface.displaySearchedGifsList(gifsData);
    }
});
```